# Error message when trying to setup Orchard CMS project

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

From the web based 'Get Started' page, using SQL Server Express with this connection string (it is correct):

```
Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=Orchard
```

The database exists & is blank.

I get this error:

```
Setup failed: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Orchard.Environment.Configuration.ShellSettings, Orchard.Data.ISessionFactoryHolder)' on type 'SqlCeCommandInterpreter'.
```

I am just following the tutorial in the O'Reilly book 'Orchard CMS up and running'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I just tried with SQL Compact - same error

Comment: I am also using localhost - with a an application pointing at c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Orchard.Source\src\Orchard.Web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Data source should likely be `.\SQLExpress` as this is the default instance if you install it

Also - it looks like you selected the "Use built in storage" option" - as it is complaining about SQLCe. If you want to use SQL express you need to choose "Use an existing SQL Server, SQL Express database"

you can look on http://www.connectionstrings.com/ to verify other details of the string

Comment: My data source is '.' > this works on other applications - it is how I have it setup.

I think you're right though - somewhere it got confused.

There 'may' be a bug in orchard here. The first time i tried to create the app, it it reported an error. Then if you fix it and resubmit the 'connection string' box goes away.

Not sure but worth looking into.

I fixed it by totally starting again from scratch.

Comment: "." is a default instance for SQL Server, but not for SQL Express. Did you specifically setup SQL Express like this? Do you also have a SQL Server instance as well. I don't think Orchard got confused here. It is more likely that the wrong radio box was selected for the type of database. Yes, there is an error where the box disappears, but selecting a different radio box and reselecting the correct one brings it back. Its not a functional issue, just a UI one.

Comment: I did specifically set it up as '.' yes. When the connection string vanishes I'm not sure if it still submits it or not - could be worth investigating anyway.

Answer (score 0):

for me, it turned out that my Connection String was incomplete. I literally hadn't copied the whole thing